# What is a maximal curve?

Tags: fx, forecasting

I came across the term **maximals** in [this article](http://forexop.com/strategy/stop-loss-profit-placements-max-returns/). Can someone explain what a maximal curve is and how you would calculate it?

Comment: you forgot to add the article :)

Comment: I understand it as a probability that the price deviates more than x pips and could be I guess calculated from historical distributions. Then just calculated as quantiles of ordered observations..similar to empirical cumulative distribution function. But I never seen it before or read the article properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article says: Taking the volatility as input these curves will tell me the probability of a maximum price (either up or down) being reached.

Using standard deviation of price data a volatility is calculated into a pips per hour number. That's nice. Based on that calculation the "maximal" gives probabilities that a market moves a particular distance over a particular time.

You calculate the maximal using a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). That article uses a random walk function and has a [spreadsheet](http://forexop.com/?wpdmact=4734) you can download.

Therefore this "maximal" can be used as a probability for stops and profit targets being hit, because they are set a certain distance away from a current price.

The problem is historical volatility is not a guide to future volatility.

I guess what you could do is get into a trade, set your stops and targets for a particular time using these maximals, and if they aren't hit - given a margin for error - you take profit anyway because the calculations were "wrong".